# why does '[self.pickerSubArray indexOfObject:self.txtSubCategory.text]' return '2147483647'?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

why does '[self.pickerSubArray indexOfObject:self.txtSubCategory.text]' return '2147483647'; while the same string value argument '[self.pickerSubArray indexOfObject:@"Mark"]' brings up 4, as desired?

Comment: 2147483647 is the maximum 32 bit integer value.

Comment: The value you see is most likely `NSNotFound` (defined to be 0x7FFFFFFF) which indicates, that the value is not found in the array

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Apple docs for [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) (which I assume your object is, based on the name) say that `indexOfObject:` returns `NSNotFound` if the object does not match any in the array. `NSNotFound` is itself defined as `NSIntegerMax` which, as others have pointed out, is the value that you are getting back.

`indexOfObject:` uses `isEqual:` to compare the items, so in theory if the text is the same then it should be working. Perhaps the text is actually different in some way that you haven't noticed, such as case ("Mark" vs. "mark") or extra padding ("Mark" vs. "Mark ").

Answer (score -1):

`indexOfObject:` returns `NSNotFound` if it can't find your exact object. `NSNotFound` is defined as `NSIntegerMax`, which is 2147483647.

Why is it doing that? I'm pretty sure indexOfObject: tests for an identical object, not an object with identical content.
e.g.

```
NSString *mark1 = [NSString stringWithString:@"Mark"];
NSString *mark2 = [NSString stringWithString:@"Mark"];
```

mark1 is not necissarily equal to mark2, because they're two different objects.

```
NSString *mark1 = [NSString stringWithObject:@"Mark"];
NSString *mark2 = mark1;
```

mark1 is equal to mark2;

BUT! Since the compiler is trying to minimize the memory footprint, it turns all literal strings in your code into one constant string. Which is why `[[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Mark"] indexOfObject:@"Mark"]` works, but `[[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Mark"] indexOfObject:textField.text]` doesn't work even if the text in textField.text is "Mark".

How do you fix it... well, indexOfObject: from the docs it looks like indexOfObject: is based on isEqual: so you should test if [self.txtSubCategory.text isEqual:@"Mark"]. to rule out the wrong value or a disconnected outlet, etc. After that, you may have to refactor to not use indexOfObject:

Comment: See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html: "Objects are considered equal if isEqual: returns YES."

Comment: Thanks Kenny. You said it all. I must have a disconnect somewhere. It may be because it is on a Modal viewController. Don't know still checking.

Comment: No -- Kenny's answer is wrong. NSArray uses `isEqual:` to determine object equality and the behavior of that method is quite well documented.   Compiler optimizations have *absolutely nothing* to do with your problem.

Answer (score -2):

Just a guess about the number origin - it's a bad integer conversion. It was very probably meant to return -1.

That kindof leads me to believe that you might have found some badness in underlying libraries/languages.

Comment: Too quick to blame the libraries. There is a lot going on here that can be a coding error. e.g. misunderstanding what indexOfObject: returns, and how it determines object equality.

Comment: The value returned by `indexOfObject:` when no match can be found is `NSNotFound`, which is defined to 0x7ffffffff. I think, that's what the OP is getting. -1 ~ 0xffffffff is a different number.